# Android ListView: load items only on scroll

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom adapter for a list view. It has 3 fields: a thumbnail and two text fields.

Once the layout is inflated, the thumbnails are downloaded from an external server.

How do i change the functionality so that the images are downloaded only when the user scrolls down.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Inflate the layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, parent, false);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
    TextView firstline = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstline);
    TextView secondline = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondline);         

    // Get information about the report
    AnimalLocationLog current = objects.get(position);

    // Get all the important information
    String species = current.getSpecies();
    String sanitizedSpecies = MiscHelpers.sanitizeString(species);
    int reportId = objects.get(position).getTrackerId();

    // Construct the URL to the image
    String imageLocation = websiteUrl + sanitizedSpecies + separator + reportId + extension;

    // Display user report          
    downloader.download(imageLocation, image);          
    firstline.setText(species);
    secondline.setText("Spotted " + current.getDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd H:m"));

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: This code looks like it will do what you require already.

Comment: @AdamS is right getView is only called when the listview needs the view which is on the screen.

Comment: Thanks @AdamS - please post an answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 0):

Add an [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) to your `ListView` with `ListView.setOnScrollListener()` and do the download in the `ScrollListener.onScroll()` method. You can use the `ListView.getLastVisiblePosition()` to figure out what list items are visible and which aren't.